# Highlight active region without transient-mark-mode

Tags: faces, mark, transient-mark-mode

Is there any way to have the region highlighted *without* `transient-mark-mode` on? I'm trying to implement [kakoune](https://github.com/mawww/kakoune/blob/master/doc/pages/keys.asciidoc) style editing in emacs and having a persistent region actually makes sense under that editing model.

EDIT: Clarification 
According to kakoune's documentation, there is always an active selection, with an anchor and a cursor. The anchor and the cursor in kakoune would correspond to the mark and point in emacs. Disabling transient mark-mode in emacs would bring it more in line with the idea of a persistent selection with an always active mark. According to the emacs manual, however, disabling transient-mark-mode disables region highlighting, since having highlighting all the time would be annoying. It is precisely this 'annoying' behavior that I'm trying to enable. The question is basically "how do I highlight the region?" Apologies for the confusing nature of the initial question. I'm new to emacs and have yet to get up to speed with all the terms.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "without transient-mark-mode" and what you mean by "persistent region".  Describe the relevant part of what is "kakoune" (not only the question should make sense even if that link is broken, but I looked at that link and that did not help me understand what you want).  Also, I recommend you rephrase your question because the answer to your current question is "yes" but I suspect you want another answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Active region means active mark. And this notion has *no meaning* outside of `transient-mark-mode`. If `transient-mark-mode` is off then the region/mark is *neither active nor inactive* -- that distinction exists only when `transient-mark-mode` is on.
2. If you change your question to just "region" instead of "active region" then sure, there are *many ways to highlight the region* (whether active or not). Do that, and I and others will no doubt provide info/references about that.

   And please specify clearly what you mean by a "persistent region". Highlighting, for example, can persist until some event, or it can persist for an entire Emacs session, or it can persist across sessions.
3. Please *describe the behavior* you want. Do not just post a link to some page that has lots of stuff on it that is, or at least seems to be, unrelated. *Specify* the behavior you are interested in. Otherwise, the question risks being closed because it is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, here's a piece of Elisp which makes it always highlight the region, without affecting anything in Emacs's behavior (other than the visual aspect of the text in the region, obviously):

```
(advice-add 'redisplay--update-region-highlight
            :around
            (lambda (orig-fun &rest args)
              (let ((transient-mark-mode t)
                    (mark-active (if (mark t) t)))
                (apply orig-fun args))))
```